# Grails Security Plugin: Where to store additional user data?

Tags: spring, security, grails

I want to use the Grails Spring Security Plugin in my app. It creates a domain class which represents a user. My research on the internet showed me that it is not good to put all the data in this class because it's loaded all the time.

My simple solution to this would be to pack the data in an additional class and then asocciate it in the security user class. Is this a good way?

Comment: Would you clarify your concern about "being loaded all the time"? Are you concerned with memory footprint, or data access time?

Comment: My concern is that the security plugin keeps the user objects in memory with all the data that isn't needed for security things. So I want to separate those and put additional profile data in a different class. And the question is wheter that solves the problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "loaded all the time", it's loaded when you authenticate. The username, password, and role names are used to build the `Authentication` instance that's stored in the HTTP session. This is checked to see if you have access rights for various URLs.

But it can make sense to partition the data into a security-related user class and an associated profile class as @Gregg describes.

You can use a custom `userDetailsService` implementation to cache data from the User class in the `Authentication` to avoid having to repeatedly load the whole thing from the database; see http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a good approach.  I've often used a Profile class to attach additional User profile data.  I've also added additional properties directly to the User class.  It probably depends on how much additional data you're talking about.